# REPLACE VALUE INTO JSON_ARRAY_T

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

I have an Array like:

```
["value_1", "value_2", "value_3"]
```

I want to replace the value_2 on the second position with value_4 in same position; using JSON_ARRAY_T.

The result must be:

```
["value_1", "value_4", "value_3"]
```

Is there any way? or I have to **remove** and **put**?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you need to replace the second value in the array, no matter what value it has, with "value_4"? Or do you need to replace the value "value_2" with "value_4", no matter in what position "value_2" is found?

Comment: You are making two assumptions there, and both are wrong. The downvote is not from me; and I understand the question perfectly well. I haven't been online since I asked you my question; you already got the right answer from another poster. Be well.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I no understand who was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/overview-of-pl-sql-object-types-for-json.html#GUID-A22995AD-A144-4A5C-AB80-A17225A56E41) says this:

> For an array, `put()` also accepts an optional third argument, `OVERWRITE`. This is a `BOOLEAN` value (default `FALSE`) that says whether to replace an existing value at the given position.

So you need to do:

```
declare
  arr JSON_ARRAY_T;
begin
  arr := JSON_ARRAY_T('["value_1", "value_2", "value_3"]');
  arr.put(1, 'value_4', true);
  dbms_output.put_line(arr.stringify);
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=105f75e108dc55ed91cabd0716314b86)